# What is the ASP notation for the value of WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY?

Tags: asp-classic, winhttp

I've searched the internet all morning.

I just want to know the value and how to notate it in asp classic.

I think it's 1 in decimal notation.

```
WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const uint WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY = 1;
const long WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY = 1;
```